# How do I set up OpenSSL for Qt on Windows 10?

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

I'm attempting to install OpenSSL on Windows 10 for use with Qt development. I've tried installing from multiple sources, adding lines to my .pro file, and adding DLL files next to the built application, yet nothing works.

I've tried building and running the Qt HTTP request example, and that can't use HTTPS either, so it's not an issue with my code or configuration.

So, where should I get OpenSSL for Windows, and what do I do after installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before.

For starters, you need to build OpenSSL 1.0.2 source code - available [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/).  You'll need to follow the build instructions in the INSTALL.W32 file. And there are some amended instructions in the INSTALL.W64 file for 64-bit builds.

The two primary DLLs you will wind up building are libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll.  (Also copy off the libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib stub files and corresponding .pdb files).

If your Qt sources are already built for OpenSSL, you can just drop these two DLLs into your Qt Bin folder (or wherever Qt5Networking.dll is loaded for your application).

If your Qt distribution is built from source, you might need to build Qt again with the `openssl-linked` option. This will enable Qt to be loaded via implicit DLL loading.

```
LIB=%LIB%;%c:\openssl\out32dll

configure -commercial release -opengl dynamic openssl-linked -force-debug-info -nomake examples -llibeay32 -lssleay32

jom
```

For a debug build to correspond to debug Qt5 binaries, you'll need to repeat the above steps, except follow the OpenSSL instructions for building debug binaries to the out32dll.dbg folder.

If your qt distribution was built with dynamic openssl loading, you just need to make sure ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are in a folder that is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!